# Xamarin UI test

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run a simple Xamarin UI test. I have already set ANDROID_HOME variable but test still throw exception (see image). I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.8.1.
Path of my android sdk is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. I have installed platfroms since 25...

[image: SDK not found]

[image]

EDIT
I made changes in user variables (add also a JAVA_HOME variable). Still not work. (see image).

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2**
**RESOLVED**
The problem was that i have multiple paths in ANDROID_HOME variable (as Cheesebaron mentioned in the comments). There is a variable in System variables called "Path" (which i didn't notice) that you need to modified and add %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools. In the same way you have to add JAVA_HOME variable (as in Junior Jiang answer).

Comment: Why do you have multiple paths for both of these? The environment variables should be a single path

Comment: I read it somwhere .. i tried it only with single path but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using visual stuido in PC.

**First**, you need to add **ANDROID_HOME** in **User variables**:

[image]

**Second**, also need to add following path inside **Path**:

[image]

**Last**, save changed and close visual studio to reopen it to check whether it works.

======================update======================

Have a try add **JAVA_HOME** in **User variables**:

[image]

and add following path inside **Path**:

[image]

Comment: tried, but still doesn't work. see edited question please

Comment: @puko Okey, you could add `JAVA_HOME` in **User variables** to have a try. I will update answer.

Comment: added also JAVA_HOME variable but same result :( (see updated question)

Comment: @puko Open the **Terminal** of PC, type `android` and `java` to check whehter the environment variables have been working.

Comment: seems they are not working. 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @puko After modifying **environment variables**, you need to close the window of **System Properties** and **Terminal** , then re-open Terminal to check. Sometimes, in order to make sure it works, we will restart the PC to make it works.

Comment: finally it is working .. see my updated question .. thank you very much

Comment: @puko Oh, got it! Glad solved that, and thanks for marking my answer.